# fetch api (GET DATA) from php file

Tags: javascript, php, get, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch values from php file

api.php

```
      <?php
      // want to fetch this value 
      $a = 'come!! fetch this value';

      ?>
```

my javascript page has code like this.(this code is not on page api.php)

```
            fetch('http://localhost/react_task/react-webpack-boilerplate/php/api.php', {
        method: 'get',
        // may be some code of fetching comes here
    }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                return response.text()
            }
            throw new Error(response.statusText)
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
```

can you please guide me how to fetch value of variable from php file by using fetch.

Comment: Simple. In your PHP page, put `echo $a;` at the end. Then when you fetch the page, it will grab the text content of the page, which is what you echo'ed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: no its dubpicate man.. @DavidR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not echoing the value, so it won't be send.

```
<?php
// want to fetch this value 
$a = 'come!! fetch this value';
echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: if i echo the value .. then definitely it will echo..... that is right ....  but i want to see value of $a on javascript page not on api page.

Comment: That's not possible, the only thing JavaScript can see is what's been echoed by PHP or what's is served by the webserver.

Comment: basically i am working on security app.. if it echo the data.. then its not uite safe..

Comment: Can you maybe explain a bit more about it? For now it looks like you need some kind of authentication?

Comment: Basically i am working with 2 servers right now,, apache and node .js....  my apache server(php file) contain public key.. and i want to fetch that public key from apache server.. this is basically i am trying to do.. just explained short of bit.... its quite long security procedure on some website.

Comment: Oke thx, than a simple echo will be sufficient, it's a public key you can give that to everyone. This wouldn't let to a security issue.

Comment: thanks man................... i got some new concept for my project just by explainibng my situation.. that is wierd.. but fine.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your php needs to output the value you want. A simple way to do this is to use `echo`. For example:

```
echo 'come!! fetch this value';
```

Comment: i don't want to echo it.. just want to keep it in variable and see the value in javascript page man.

Answer (score -1):

You should use echo to display it in php then it will be available in you JavaScript reponse.